# php Is it different if I put my <?php?> code at the top of the body or at the bottom

Tags: php, post, position

hello  please help me understand this because i run a code and i put that code in the bottom and it has errors here it is as u can see it has errors here it is [THE ERROR!](http://prntscr.com/856wal)

```
<html>
    <body>

    <form action="#" method="post">
    Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='add'>+
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='subtract'>-
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='multiply'>*
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='divide'>/
    <br>
    Num2:<input name="num2"> 
    Result:<input value='<?php echo  $result;?>'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>
   <?php
      function add($x,$y){

           $add=$x + $y;
           return $add;

       }
       function subtract($x,$y){

           $subtract=$x - $y;
           return $subtract;

       }
       function multiply($x,$y){

           $multiply=$x * $y;
           return $multiply;

       }
       function divide($x,$y){

           $divide=$x / $y;
           return $divide;

       }

       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           $x=$_POST['num1'];
           $y=$_POST['num2'];
           if(isset($_POST['express'])){
               $z=$_POST['express'];
            if($x == '' or $y == '' ){
                echo 'input a number';
               }
           else if($z == 'add'){
               $result= add($x,$y);  
           }
           else if($z=='subtract'){
               $result= subtract($x,$y);

           }
           else if($z=='multiply'){
               $result= multiply($x,$y);

           }
           else{
               $result= divide($x,$y);

           }

           }



       }


    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

WHILE here is the working version i put all my codes at the top of the body

```
<html>
    <body>
     <?php
      function add($x,$y){

           $add=$x + $y;
           return $add;

       }
       function subtract($x,$y){

           $subtract=$x - $y;
           return $subtract;

       }
       function multiply($x,$y){

           $multiply=$x * $y;
           return $multiply;

       }
       function divide($x,$y){

           $divide=$x / $y;
           return $divide;

       }

       if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
           $x=$_POST['num1'];
           $y=$_POST['num2'];
           if(isset($_POST['express'])){
               $z=$_POST['express'];
            if($x == '' or $y == '' ){
                echo 'input a number';
               }
           else if($z == 'add'){
               $result= add($x,$y);  
           }
           else if($z=='subtract'){
               $result= subtract($x,$y);

           }
           else if($z=='multiply'){
               $result= multiply($x,$y);

           }
           else{
               $result= divide($x,$y);

           }

           }



       }


    ?>
    <form action="#" method="post">
    Num1:<input name="num1"><br>
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='add'>+
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='subtract'>-
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='multiply'>*
    <input type='radio'  name='express' value='divide'>/
    <br>
    Num2:<input name="num2"> 
    Result:<input value='<?php echo  $result;?>'>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">
    </form>

    </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: At the time of `echo $result`, you haven't defined `$result` yet - functions may be hoisted, but the processing code that defines `$result` most certainly is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the first example you are printing `$result` before declaring it and in the second example you are printing `$result` after declaring it. Since in the first example `$result` is not declared and you are trying to print it in this line:

```
Result:<input value='<?php echo  $result;?>'>
```

that is why you are getting error `Undefined Variable`.

Answer (score 0):

In first code example you're trying to echo variable which is declared later, for example can you tell someone "I'm 20 years old" if you don't know how old are you.

While in second example you have declared variable (you know how old are you) and you can output it.